# In Yocto, how to include header files from another recipes

Tags: yocto

My program depends on the `poco` recipes, which provides both the header files and shared libraries. However, I cannot make use of the header files from `poco` in my recipe, which leads to the error `Poco/Delegate.h: No such file for directory`.

How do I make the header available at build time for my software package?

Here is an example recipe:

```
SUMMARY = ""
DESCRIPTION = ""
AUTHOR = ""
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""
HOMEPAGE = ""
BUGTRACKER = ""

S = "${WORKDIR}"

SRC_URI = " file://foo.cpp \
            file://CMakeLists.txt \
"

inherit pkgconfig cmake

DEPENDS_foo = "poco"
RDEPENDS_foo = "poco"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/${bindir}
    install -m 755 ${S}/foo ${D}/${bindir}
}

FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/foo"
```

Comment: basically that look correct, assuming that your recipe is called foo_1.0.bb or such. the DEPENDS doesn't need the package identifier, so maybe its already enough to change DEPENDS_foo to DEPENDS. and of course, your CMakeLists.txt has to do the proper pkg-config invocation.

Answer (score 4):

Manual recommends:

> Recipes should never populate the sysroot directly:

Recommended way is (poco recipe should do something similar):

> Files should be installed into standard locations:

```
...
do_install() {
...
    install -d ${D}${includedir}
    install -m 0755 ${S}/myapi.h ${D}${includedir}/
...
}
...
```

Than, include **poco recipe** as a build dependency of **foo.bb** :

DEPENDS += "poco"

And compile normally.

Answer (score 3):

We can use **provider** and **user** to illustrate this case, the package (recipe) provides a header file to be used by another package (recipe) is the **provider**, the package (recipe) use a header file from another package (recipe) is the **user**.

First we change the provider's recipe (**myprovider.bb**) to export the header file -- **myapi.h**,

```
...
do_install() {

    install -d ${D}/${bindir}
    install -m 755 ${B}/hello_provider ${D}/${bindir}

    install -d ${D}${libdir}/lib_myprovider/
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/myapi.h ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${libdir}/lib_myprovider/
}
...
```

Secondly we change the user's recipe (**myuser.bb**) to refer the header file -- **myapi.h**

```
...
do_compile () {    

    ${CC} ${WORKDIR}/main.c -o hello_user ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -I${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/lib_myprovider/ 
}

# file dependency declaration
FILES_${PN} = "${libdir}/lib_myprovider"

# package dependency declaration
DEPENDS += "myprovider"
...
```

At last, rebuild myprovider.bb and myuser.bb recipes, it should work.

Comment: but where STAGING_DIR_TARGET is defined ?

Comment: Could we use STAGING_INCDIR instead?
Also, could the do_populate_sysroots be used instead of do_install?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DEPENDS` to have dependency with "poco" recipe and it would build and populate "poco" recipe's headers and libs into your recipe's sysroot.

Similar way you have to mention the export paths in the provider's recipe with `FILES_*( * - package type)`